# Error while CMaking Qt5::Gui. libEGL.so not found although it exists

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to compile simple Qt GUI program on Ubuntu via CMake and it fails with the following error:

**The imported target "Qt5::Gui" references the file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so" but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

- The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
- An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.**

I searched online and I tried various solutions including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616065/the-imported-target-qt5gui-references-the-file-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-li): Over here the problem seems to be sym link between libEGL.so and libEGL.so.1. But in my case that does not seem be the problem. There seems to be good link [image].

I thought the problem might be because of absolute path of shared libraries as discussed over [here.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101590/absolute-paths-to-egl-library-in-libqt5gui-so-since-qt-5-12-1) But I do not have absolute paths as shown below:

[image]

I installed mesa libraries using via libegl1-mesa-dev. I still have the errors. My Qt version is 5.12.8. I am under the impression that they got rid of that similar bug by this version. If not, please let know.

The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(LinuxProject1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) 
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(LinuxProject1 LinuxProject1.cpp MainWindow.cpp MainWindow.ui)
target_link_libraries(LinuxProject1 Private Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: How did you install Qt5? Is the Qt provided by the repositories or have you used the online installer? what is your ubuntu version? Also provide a [mre]. Finally run `sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev`

Comment: I installed Qt5 via repositories(sudo apt-get install qt5-default). The Ubuntu version is 20.04. The thing is it is not even compiling. The CMake is throwing error during compilation.

Comment: Show the CMakeLists.txt, also be guided by https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html#build-a-gui-executable

Comment: Okay, I have added CMakeLists.txt in the question. I still get the same error after running the command you mentioned.